# Почему не происходит запись в файл?

Tags: pascal

```
const N=30;
var Buf:array[1..N] of word;
f:file;
Bufsize:integer;

Procedure PutToBuf(put:integer);
begin
Bufsize:=Bufsize+1;
Buf[Bufsize]:=put;
if Bufsize = N then
begin
     BlockWrite(f,Buf,60);
     Bufsize:=0;
end;
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы по 30кб записывалось в файл блоками. Все работает, при запуске ошибок нет, но почему-то файл всегда пустой и ничего не записывает, в чем трабла? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Весь код покажи, по одной процедуре непонятно как ты всё это дело вызываешь!

Comment: вроде разобрался уже сам :) только вопросик еще маленький: как считывать инфу из файла блогами, т.е. сначало 30кб обработали потом еще 30 и до конца?

Comment: как и записывать только наоборот считывать :)

Comment: 1. Тут не по 30кбайт, а всего лишь по 60байт
2. Думаю, должно быть BlockWrite(f,Buf,N); размер одной записи определяется по типу Buf.
3. Для считывания аналогично, BlockRead(f,Buf,N);

Comment: помоему тут после assignFile нужен rewrite

Comment: В этой процедуре не обязательно, они должны быть в вызывающем коде. Предполагается что они там есть.

Comment: Уже даавно выше написал весь код напиши.

Comment: А закрывать файл кто будет?

Comment: Кто-кто, вызывающий код.

Answer (score 1):

Потому как Close(f); надо ставить после записи в файл :D